# What is the difference between manual and auto checkout in TFS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

When we edit a code,TFS automatically checks out the file. However, there is an option to manually checkout any file.Is there any difference between two. Also does checking out manually locks the file to other users?

Comment: what all did you try put the code here in your question

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference, and why don't you do some research before asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually checking out the files give you more options including the ability to pick the files. However that only works if you are using a server workspace that communicated with the server. If you have a local workspace then there is no communication f for a checkout.

Auto checkout just does a non-locking local checkout with local workspaces. For server windows it honors the configuration of the team project were you can globally set one person checkout for all files.